# If condition show error for radio button id

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following input tags inside table in asp.net

```
<td class="style18">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkContentTone" onclick="enableGroupBoxTone()" 
                    runat="server" Text="Content Tone" CssClass="ChkBoxStyle"/>&nbsp;
</td>
<td class="styleCntTon">
    <input type="radio" id="rdBtnPositive" name="q2" title="Posotivetitle" value="positive"/>
    <label for="rdbtnPositive" class="RadioGroup">Positive</label>
    <input type="radio" id="rdBtnNegative" name="q2" title="Negativetitle" value="negative"/>
    <label for="rdBtnNegative" class="RadioGroup">Negative</label>
    <input type="radio" id="rdBtnNeutral" name="q2" title="Neutraltitle" value="neutral"/> 
    <label for="rdBtnNeutral" class="RadioGroup">Neutral</label>
</td>
```

but when I put an `if` condition in, the radio button's the show an error.

[image: error when if condition included]

Any ideas why this is occurring?

Comment: are you missing `runat="server"`?

Comment: definitely.. Runat server missing..

Comment: i added runat="server" but still i have problem :(

Comment: now I got my result :) thanks to all my Repend(Reply-Friend) :)

Comment: soory for relying late. I post this from ofc and left after it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Asp.net controls:

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

The markup you posted does not include server side controls hence those controls cannot be accessed via server side code.

Looking at what you want seems like you would need an `asp:RadioButton`

once you add a `asp:radiobutton` you can access these controls in your server side code.

Change this:

`<input type="radio" id="rdBtnPositive" name="q2" title="Posotivetitle" value="positive"/><label for="rdbtnPositive" class="RadioGroup">Positive</label>`

To this:

`<asp:RadioButton id="rdBtnPositive" Label="Positive" runat="server" />`

Then you can do:

```
if(rdBtnPositive.Checked)
 {
  //code it...
 }
```

You'll need to do that for all three radiobutton's, each should have a unique id and be a server side control, namely `asp:RadioButton`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use asp:RadioButton to be able to access in code behind.

So basically replace all "input" tags with "asp:RadioButton" and remove non sensible properties like Type.

asp:RadioButton usage example